# Need help a regarding javascript routine

Tags: javascript

i have two routine one return dropdown value as array and other one return highest close value from array based on given input. the problem is function `closest()` is not working and i also not being able to understand.

### here is full code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //var array = [00, 05, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55];
    //var number = 05;
    //alert(closest(number, array)); // display output here


    function closest(num, arr) {
        var next = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);


        for (var val = 0; val < arr.length; val++) {
            if (arr[val] >= num && arr[val] < next) next = arr[val];
        }

        curr = next;

        curr = (curr >= 10) ? curr : '0' + curr; //If result is 5, to display '05' instead of '5'
        return curr;
    }


    function cboValueToArray(targetid) {
        var $target = $("select[id*=" + targetid + "] option");
        var results = [];
        $target.each(function () {
            var val = $(this).val();
            if (val !== '') results.push(val);
        });
        //alert(results.toString());
        return results;
    }
    alert(closest(09,cboValueToArray('DropDownList1').toString()));

});
```

Comment: closest is expecting an array asits second argument: `closest(num, arr) {`, but you appear to be passing it a string: `cboValueToArray('DropDownList1').toString()`

Comment: if u print this `cboValueToArray('DropDownList1').toString()` then u see this is returning an array.

Comment: The toString() method returns a string representing the object it was called on. Could you make a JSFiddle or similar?

Comment: here is the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/zby2nrna/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot construct an array like this:

```
var cboarry = '[' + cboValueToArray('DropDownList1') + ']';
```

This will result in a string, regardless of what alert says.
You can check this with:

```
console.log(typeof cboarry); //string
```

Also, in your `closest` function, you are referencing a variable `number`, that should be `num`.

Corrected code:

```
function closest(num, arr) {
    var next = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
    for (var val = 0; val < arr.length; val++) {
        if (arr[val] >= num && arr[val] < next) next = arr[val];
    }

    curr = next;
    curr = (curr >= 10) ? curr : '0' + curr; 
    return curr;
}


function cboValueToArray(targetid) {
    var $target = $("select[id*=" + targetid + "] option");
    var results = [];
    $target.each(function () {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val !== '') results.push(val);
    });

    return results;
}

var cboarry = cboValueToArray('DropDownList1');
alert(closest(9, cboarry));
```